# alternative way for trigger click event for mobile

Tags: jquery

I've made a gallery which is working on desktop well but when viewed in mobile the next click function is not working. So I'm looking forward for alternative way for trigger click event something like this: `nextImg.trigger('click');`

Comment: what about `touchstart`.?

Comment: trigger('touchstart') ?

Comment: Yeah that's what i meant.

Comment: I tried like this trigger('touchstart click') but now it's even not working in desktop

Comment: I've also tried like triggerAll http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850625/jquery-trigger-multiple-events but also couldn't get worked.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried nextImg.trigger("click")? Either this or touchstart should work.
If not, there may be a problem with your mobile not supporting jquery for desktop. You can try using jquery Mobile, it should work for both mobile and computer browsers.

Comment: just nextImg.trigger('touchstart') would work for both mobile and desktop