# Just want to trigger keyup/keydown/space event form in jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How to trigger an `keyup` event?

If have an text field with id item and if I trigger an event with space a space must be added to text field.
I just want it trigger an event from JavaScript console

```
    $('#item').keydown();
    $('#item').keypress();
    $('#item').keyup();
```

Comment: `just want it trigger an event from JavaScript console` means?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use** "input blur" instead of keypress, keyup, keydown:

```
$('#item').on('input blur', function(e) {
   // do something
});
```

**Here is an example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#item').on('input blur', function(e, customData) {
    
     var data = $(this).val() ;
     if(typeof customData !== 'undefined') {
       data = customData;
     }
    
     $('.check').text('yourItemId: ' + data);
  });
  
  $('button').click(function() {
      $('#item').trigger('blur', ["Hello"]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   Type something:
  <input id="item" name="code" maxlength="19">
  <span class="check"></span>
  <br>
  <button>Trigger input-blur-event test</button>
```

**Notice:**
`.trigger()` accepts online one event!
Here is a nice way from a other user to setup new function triggerAll: [jQuery .trigger() multiple events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850625/jquery-trigger-multiple-events)

Comment: these events fire hen i do some thing on elements but i need to trigger it automatically please let me know if you are not getting my point

Comment: @ManjuKb okay, iam sure that iam understand you right. Pls check the snippet update. The "$('#item').trigger('blur')" will trigger your event. It can also be keypress, keyup or keydown instead of blur.

Comment: tied this but not working 
var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { keyCode: 32 } );
$('#item').trigger(e);

actually i'm working  typeahead input box i need to get list of available values once i press space or some letters 
this is will not work if use $('#item').va("value") 
hope  u got my point :-)

Comment: You have wrong syntax: e = jQuery.Event( 'keypress' ); e.keyCode = 32;
can you create a jsfiddle ? that would be help i think :)